# Angularjs: how to show few letter of an email address like r***.****@g****.com

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

First of all sorry if this is very common already, but I was having a hard time finding the solution.

I saw in different places that for security reason people show only some letters of an email address and hide other characters with `*` for example `r**.****@h****.com`. I'm not sure how to achieve this.

I'm using angular and from my scope, I'm getting the email value. I wanted to show the email like this format on my web page. how can I achieve this? Any example or suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: create two html element like`<span>` one is for masking other one is for originlal. show relavent element at time with user action

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure what it's called so that I can search and see some example. I just found from your comment it's called masking

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pipe that does that string transformation logic.

Create a filter/pipe that take the email as full, transfer it via email regex which capture the (first part)@(second part).(extension) of the email and then change some of the letters in the groups you want and combine them to another string and return that other string as result.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a angularJS filter to hide few text in email like this:

```
app.filter('hideEmail', function() {
  return function(input) {
     var arr = input.split("@");
      // process text before @
       var letter1 = arr[0][0] + "*".repeat(arr[0].length - 2) + arr[0].slice(-1);
      // process text after @
       var letter2 = arr[1][0] + "*".repeat(arr[1].length - 2) + arr[1].slice(-1);
      return letter1 + "@" + letter2;
  }
});
```

and use this filter in HTML like this: `<p>{{email | hideEmail}}</p>`

Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/PzRZqoIelJjWbsQWaQtR?p=preview